# How to use string variable multiple times to make regex expression

Tags: c++, regex

Just wanting to use a string variable multiple times in the construction of my regex variable.  I want to match on a word whether it is the word itself or the same word with a number appended at the end of it (up to two digits)  For example, suppose I have this:

```
string str1 = "MyWord";    //I want this to pass
string str2 = "MyWord2";   //I want this to pass
string str3 = "MyWor";     //I want this to fail

//This works, but I don't want to use a string literal, I want to use str1
const regex re("MyWord|MyWord\\d{1,2}");

//I need the variable to be used multiple times in the regex
const regex re(str1 | str1\\d{1,2}) 


if (regex_match (str2, re )){
  cout << "We have a match";
}
```

Comment: To whoever answers, if I have to use two regular expressions to do this, than you can just say that, I was just trying to avoid that.

Comment: `const regex re(str1 | str1\\d{1,2})` -- The issue has nothing to do with regular expressions.  You're expecting C++ to be some sort of regular expression parser internally.  It isn't.  You have to build the string yourself, and give it to the regex functions.

Comment: Shouldn't your regex example be shorter, i.e. `"MyWord\\d{0,2}"` ? i.e. Since you want 0, 1, or 2 digits on the end?

Comment: @StephenQuan yeah, the word may or may not have a digit at the end of it.

Comment: Note that the regex shown will match successfully on `"MyWord123"`, it will just ignore the `3`. Is that what you really want? Or do you want the match to fail if there are more then 2 digits present?

Comment: I want the regex to fail if more than two digits are present.

Comment: Then, wouldn't you need to terminate the regex (at both ends), say, `"^MyWord\\d{0,2}$"` to indicate that nothing can come before or after?

Comment: Yes @StephenQuan, thank you.  That is how it is done in JavaScript too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate your `str1` variable with string literals that represent the remaining pieces of the regex expression, eg:

```
const regex re(str1 + "|" + str1 + "\\d{1,2}");
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the duplication of `str1` using C++20's [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (or [equivalent](https://fmt.dev)), for instance:

```
const regex re(format("{0}|{0}\\d{{1,2}}", str1));
```

However, that being said, since you are really just looking for a single word with an optional number following it, you can simplify the regex expression to this instead:

```
const regex re(str1 + "\\d{0,2}");
```